# clothing 2D pattern from Inkscape and simulate in Blender

Tags: svg

I am doing the project that, drawing 2D pattern in Inkscape, and export it as SVG file, then import to the Blender and simulate the cloth with the human model.

I draw the 2D patterns, and imported it into the Blender.
However, the patterns are not like vector object but just line shape.

How can I use 2D pattern as a vector object so that I can put it on the human model in Blender?

Thank you very much and if you need more information or detail, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In inkscape the paths need to be filled, and be a closed path.

For a filled shape in blender:

In the Curve->Shape tab make the curve 2D and set the  Fill Mode to Both (Front and Back)

[image]

If your idea is to use it as texture on a material, then you need to convert the image to a a raster format (tiff or whatever other format you are confortable with) Blender cannot use pahts as texture.

If what you want is to create a shape and fold it or wrap it around objects, then SVGs will need to be converted to meshes.

Comment: Thank you :) 
What I want to do is making 3D cloths for human model using 2D pattern from Inkscape,
And I want to simulate how tight it is width tension map.
So, the first step was to make 2D pattern, and I finished it. But, I need to create 3D cloths with the pattern. My hardness is coming from this step. 
I do not know how to add image, so I will add answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am doing now.
Now, I need to sew two body patterns so that that two patterns become one cloth.
I filled the lines by following your description.
What and how should I do for the next step?
Is there any tool to sew them to make a cloth?

[image: imported pattern and set its position]