# How do I enable cloth sewing for this imported SVG?

Tags: cloth-simulation, svg

I have a question about sewing 2D pattern to 3d cloth in the Blender.

My previous question was on this link:
[clothing 2D pattern from Inkscape and simulate in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183574/clothing-2d-pattern-from-inkscape-and-simulate-in-blender/183947#183947)?

I imported an SVG file made with Inkscape.
By helping with this answers, I could import 2D pattern to Blender and fill the object line in both (front & back).

Now, I tried to follow second answer to my previous question, but in object properties, my patterns are recognised differently than the makehuman body model.
Therefore, in the object properties, some menus are not visible.

How can I solve this problem and how to sew these two patterns into 3D cloth?

[image: This is human model from makehuman]

This picture is human model from Makehuman

[image]

And this picture is my pattern selected.

If you see the pictures, on the right side pallet, the green icon is also different on right upper as well as "enable physics for" menu which is shown now on right below.

Answer (score 0):

Check these settings:

[image]

you also need to add a new vertex group to define what should be "sewed"

[image]

once done, play the simulation (play button, spacebar or shift-spacebar).

Comment: Okay, I did that setting on the human model, and made a group. However, as you wrote, patterns should be in the group, but I cannot add those to the group Because object data properties is different to human model and the patterns. 
Human model is green triangle symbol, but patterns are green curved symbol. 
And you can tell what is different from pictures in the question. While human model has a lot of meshes, but the pattern has only edge lines which are in different color.
What is different those color by the way?